# Var filled with object suddenly null, what happened?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fatal-error

I am building this form in symfony 2.0 and for some reason when I retrieve a object from the db and put it into an object it is gone when I want to save it so I get the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MelvinLoos\CMS\CoreBundle\Entity\Page::setParent()
must be an instance of MelvinLoos\CMS\CoreBundle\Entity\Page, null given, 
called in vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Util\PropertyPath.php on line 347
and defined in src\MelvinLoos\CMS\CoreBundle\Entity\Page.php line 233
```

My code:

```
public function popupChildAction($parentid)
{
    $entity  = new Page();
    $entity->setWebsite($this->getWebsite());

    $parent = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MelvinLoosCMSCoreBundle:Page')
    ->findOneById($parentid);

    if (!$parent)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No parent found with given id: "' . $parentid . '"');
    }
    $entity->setParent($parent);

    $entity->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
    //$entity->setPageType();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new PageChildType(), $entity);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

    }

    return $this->render('MelvinLoosCMSCoreBundle:Page:new_popup.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
            'parent' => $parent
    ));
}
```

As you can see I put in a if statement to check if $parent is filled and I also tried a var_dump to double check, it is defiantly filled with an object. But for some reason when I call the setParent() function of the entity object it fills it with null.

Comment: var_dump($parent) before the if(!$parent), what does it say?

Comment: We need to see your function setParent() from Page class

Comment: If you look at the error, it is not the call on your controller which is giving the error (the $entity->setParent($parent); line) but rather, a call that symfony makes at \Symfony\Component\Form\Util\PropertyPath.php, so the error is produced at some other point in code. My guess is that it has something to do with your PageChildType. Can you post the code for that?

Comment: It seems that, your form type has a `parent` field, and when you bind the form, it tries to set null on parent (because parent was not submitted). The error is thrown because your setParent method is `setParent(Page $parent)`, and not `setParent(Page $parent = null)`, so it does not accept null. I would just suggest to remove the parent field from your form type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally forgot that I had this question still floating around... Anyway I got around my problem, still don't know why I got the error but I solved it with quite a easy solution.

Instead of setting the parent for the child, I did the reverse and set the child for the parent. My code is the following (There is also new code in there that's irrelevant because I fixed it some time ago).

```
public function popupChildAction($parentid)
{
    $parent = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MelvinLoosCMSCoreBundle:Page')
    ->findOneById($parentid);

    if (!$parent)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No parent found with given id: "' . $parentid . '"');
    }
    $entity  = new Page();
    $entity->setWebsite($this->getWebsite());
    $entity->setCreatedBy($this->getUser());
    $form   = $this->createForm(new PageChildType(), $entity);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $parent->setChildren($entity);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));

    }

    return $this->render('MelvinLoosCMSCoreBundle:Page:new_popup.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
            'parent' => $parent
    ));
}
```

Like I said there is newer code that is irrelevant but what it's all about is the part with
    `$parent->setChildren($entity);` and now it works... hope this helps someone!
Thanks for everyone that gave input!

Answer (score 0):

Melvin you have the check if the form is submitted and to get your entity from the form.
Can you try like this?

```
    $form   = $this->createForm(new PageChildType(), $entity);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entity = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }
    }
```